# React: How to add new value to props from imported file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am (very) new to React and have been given the task of adding some data to a component that's being brought in from another file. This file spits out some JSON and I want to access certain pieces of data from it, for example:

```
config.forms.enquiry.title
```

I am importing the file fine - no problems there. But I am not sure how to include `config` into my props.

I found a working example, in another file, and have copied what it does. My code is as such

Brings in file with JSON:

```
import { withSettings } from 'services/settingsFile';
```

Add config in render function:

```
render () {
    const styles = getStyles(this.props, this.context, this.state);
    const { config } = this.props;
    // other stuff
```

Add to propTypes:

```
enquiryForm.propTypes = {
    config: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    // other stuff
```

Add to compose:

```
export const enquiryForm = compose(
    withSettings,
    // other stuff
```

However, I get the error:

> Failed context type: The context `config` is marked as required in
>   `n`, but its value is `undefined`.

And from here I am not sure what to do. I know it's a tough question, but I know very little about React and have been thrown in the deep end.

Would anyone know what/where I should be searching for to fix this?

Comment: I'm just brainstorming here, but maybe you're trying to read from the file before its' actually loaded. Have you tried doing console.log(this.props) inside componentDidMount() to see if you're able to read from the file?

Comment: @MstrQKN I tried this but componentDidMount doesn't fire. I think the errors stop it from reaching this stage.

Comment: @MstrQKN update: I removed the code that was breaking things and added the console.log inside a componentDidMount. Unfortunetly it shows that config is empty.

Answer (score 0):

If you can import it like,

```
import { withSettings } from 'services/settingsFile';
```

why dont you use it like,

```
const { config } = withSettings;
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the issue was that there was no wrapping element setting `config` as am attribute.

I had to go up a level to where my component was being brought in and wrap:

```
<SettingsFile config={window.settingsFile}>
```

around:

```
<Component conf={config} />
```

Then, the component I was working on was able to read `config`.